# Expand DIV to its UL content

Tags: html, css

I have a **div** container and a **ul** within it. I want that the **div** be expanded to its content **ul**. I've tried everything I found (overflow:hidden, clearfix etc ...), but nothing worked.

UPDATE: originally this is a slider with a crossfade effect, where the images are overlapped with each other. So, the solution which causes that the images will be in a column (same left, but different top values) doesn't good for me.
Please, show me the pure HTML/CSS solution, without JS.

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.slider img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" style="max-width: 880px;">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any" style="width:100%"></li>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/tech" style="width:100%"></li>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/animals" style="width:100%"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you need your li items to be positioned one by one

Comment: li position absolute is causing the issue , if possible try to solve using floats

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: Check answer it will help you may be..

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line of code from your CSS:

```
li {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you want content (images) to appear in line, use the following code:

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Not good. This is a slider, which contains overlapped images for a crossfade effect. If I remove "position: absolute;" then images will be in a column one below the other (not overlapped). "display:inline-block" is wrong too. The same issue then if removed the position/absolute.

Comment: rest you can achieve by writing some js. For more details please check this: https://www.daniweb.com/digital-media/ui-ux-design/threads/482811/simple-image-slider-html-css-js

Comment: I believe it can be solved without JS. I need the HTML/CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use following css:

```
.slider {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
   list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}

li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

For creating pure CSS slider check this:
http://www.blogohblog.com/cool-slider-css3-html/

Comment: Thank you , but it is totally useless. Did you try it?